# How to wrap links into ul li in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

My apologize for syntactic illiteracy, I didn't have to deal with Ruby, but it is necessary to wrap links in the ul> li list (ul>li>a instead of a)

```rb
def links_to_hashtags(hashtags = object.hashtags)
  hashtags.map(&:to_s).map do |hashtag|
    # XXX transitional
    url = h.hashtag_page_enabled? && h.logged_out? ? h.tag_path(hashtag.downcase) : h.hashtag_friends_path(q: hashtag.downcase)
    h.link_to "##{hashtag}", url, dir: h.html_dir(hashtag)
  end.join(' ').html_safe
end
```

I tried this way but it has some syntax errors:

```rb
def links_to_hashtags(hashtags = object.hashtags)
  hashtags.map(&:to_s).map do |hashtag|
    # XXX transitional
    url = h.hashtag_page_enabled? && h.logged_out? ? h.tag_path(hashtag.downcase) : h.hashtag_friends_path(q: hashtag.downcase)
    h.content_tag :ul, class: 'fancy' do
    h.concat h.content_tag :li,
    h.link_to "##{hashtag}", url, dir: h.html_dir(hashtag)
  end.join(' ').html_safe
end
```

Many thanks for thе response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def links_to_hashtags(hashtags = object.hashtags)
  h.content_tag :ul, class: 'fancy' do
    hashtags.map(&:to_s).each do |hashtag|
      concat h.content_tag :li do
        concat link_to_hashtag(hashtag)
      end
    end
  end  
end

def link_to_hashtag(hashtag)
  # prefer if ... else over unreadably long ternary expressions
  url = if h.hashtag_page_enabled? && h.logged_out? 
    h.tag_path(hashtag.downcase) 
  else 
    h.hashtag_friends_path(q: hashtag.downcase) 
  end
  h.link_to ['#', hashtag].join, url, dir: h.html_dir(hashtag)
end
```

Each of the content helpers like `content_tag` creates its own string buffer. When you use `concat` in the block you're writing into the buffer of that tag - just like when you use `<%=` in ERB. This removes the need to do clunky string concatenation and deal with the html tags getting escaped.

However this really is something that your should consider using [a partial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)  for instead.

```
<ul class="fancy">
  <% hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
    <li><%= link_to_hashtag(hashtag) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```